# How to unmount device from a path hidden by another mounted device?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, kernel

I have *olddevice* mounted to */mnt* with:

```
$ mount olddevice /mnt
```

I would like to change the device at */mnt* mount point. For this purpose, I simply mount *newdevice* on top of it:

```
$ mount newdevice /mnt
```

With that, processes that still have file descriptors on *olddevice* can keeps working on old device, but new processes using */mnt* will use *newdevice*.

I can detect when *olddevice* is not used anymore and decide to unmount it.
My problem is how to unmount it:

```
$ umount olddevice
umount: olddevice: umount failed: Invalid argument.
```

Is it possible to directly unmount it? Or is it mandatory to unmount *newdevice* first (I do not want that) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not already running with mount propagation enabled e.g. as per systemd defaults, run this first:

```
mount --make-rshared /
```

Then:

```
mkdir /root.orig
mount --rbind / /root.orig
mount --make-rprivate /root.orig/mnt

mount newdevice /mnt
...
umount -R /root.orig/mnt    # instead of umount olddevice
```

**Then safely disassemble the magic - taking care not to unmount your entire system:**

```
mount --make-rprivate /root.orig
umount -l /root.orig
rmdir /root.orig
```

---

Usually, I like to use the recursive variants of `mount` / `umount` commands.  You say you started with only one filesystem mounted underneath `/mnt`.  In the above sequence, I used `umount -R /root.orig/mnt`.  If there was also a filesystem mounted on a *sub*directory of `/mnt`, this `umount -R` command might fail half-way through.  I.e. because there are no open files on the submount, but there are still some open files on the main mount.  IMO this feels similar to how `umount -l` works.  `umount -l /path` disassembles and detaches a mount tree, and each independent filesystem is shut down as soon as it has no open files.

Comment: I am doing other weird mounts with multiple mount points and I am wondering why `mount --make-rprivate /root.orig` does not work instead of `mount --make-rprivate /root.orig/mnt`.

Comment: @rools It's essential that `/root.orig` is a "shared" copy of `/`, not "private". That's what makes the umount operation propagate from `/root.orig/mnt`, to the other copy at `/mnt`.

Comment: (Assuming I understand what you are asking correctly. If this doesn't make sense, you might be better off writing a full scenario in a question, and pointing the question out to me).

Comment: Yes you totally got it. You are right. I thought it was another problem as I have a weird behavior but it is because I have a particular scenario. I may ask a different question. Thanks!